siesta: Why are graphene nanoribbons with finite gaps used as electrodes without needing much more screening layers?
I did know one should use bulk-like metallic electrodes to avoid problems with screening and Fermi-level definition, and if I have to use semiconductors as electrodes, I need extra screening layers in my device, as mentioned in the previous question Why can graphene nanoribbons be safely used as electrdes, despite having a finite band gap?.
However, in my case, As my previous unanswered question mentioned(please! if anyone can help),siesta: current-voltage threshold value is not consistent with the band gap value, there is finite gap of my armchair graphene nanoribbon and I didn't use extra screening layers. I even tried shorter devices but TranSiesta was very willing to finish the calculations and did not warn me about anything.
So could anyone tell me why are graphene nanoribbons with finite gaps used as electrodes without needing much more screening layers?
